# Dump pickle file and get download without saving it anywhere in Flask App

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, pickle, pem

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
      flash('No file part')
      return redirect(request.url)

    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
    ...Processing my multiple uploaded files in Flask App...
    ...
    b64_encoded_list = base64.b64encode(json_encoded_list)
    print(b64_encoded_list)
    ## b64_encoded_list is a simple string ##
    buffer = BytesIO()
    buffer.write(b64_encoded_list)
    buffer.seek(0)
    flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
    return send_file(buffer, mimetype="image/jpg", attachment_filename="license.pem", as_attachment=True)
```

Now I am able to send and download at web app part but .pem file is corrupted as b64_encoded_list contains b64 encoding of a string stored in .pem files. But after downloading the file from web app, and again reading it back giving me a error - encrypted = pickle.load(open(pemfile, "rb"))

Error - UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'W'.

How to resolve this I have also used mimetype - application/x-x509-ca-cert, but still same error.

Please help on this!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the output to a file, you need to write it to a file-like object ( eg a in-memory file ).

You can use `io.BytesIO`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO

Afterwards, you send it to the Client.

Comment: Ohkk then how will I send to client make download a .pem file format at client end??

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: return send_file(BytesIO(b64_encoded_list.content), mimetype="application/x-x509-ca-cert", attachment_filename="file.pem", as_attachment=True)

Note - b64_encoded_list is a string.

I have tried this but it is not working, can you please help me out in this!!

Comment: buffer = BytesIO()
buffer.write(b64_encoded_list)
buffer.seek(0)
return send_file(buffer, mimetype="application/x-x509-ca-cert",attachment_filename="license.pem", as_attachment=True)

I have done this and got success in getting downloaded at client end but that .pem is corrupted as it contains base64 encoding to get the original string back but a new error comes when trying to get the string back from the downloaded file - UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'W'.

Comment: I think you should write down (for yourself) a list what should happen in which succession and then compare this to your code, ie what you are doing. I am not entirely clear what you want to achieve, and I do not know what you want in a .pem file (pem is usally used for certificates). I am sure you can figure it out on your own. Best of luck!